# How to use $lookup as INNER JOIN in MongoDB Aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have used `$lookup` in my aggregate query.
But as I am seeing it works as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

> I want to fetch exact matches document(INNER JOIN) with `$lookup`.

Is there any way to get it done?

This is my `inventory` collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "sku" : "abc",
    "description" : "product 1",
    "instock" : 120
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "sku" : "def",
    "description" : "product 2",
    "instock" : 80
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "sku" : "ijk",
    "description" : "product 3",
    "instock" : 60
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "sku" : "jkl",
    "description" : "product 4",
    "instock" : 70
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "sku" : null,
    "description" : "Incomplete"
}
```

This is my `orders` collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "item" : "abc",
    "price" : 12,
    "quantity" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "item" : "jkl",
    "price" : 20,
    "quantity" : 1
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 10,
    "item" : "jklw",
    "price" : 20,
    "quantity" : 1
}
```

And this is query

```
db.getCollection('inventory').aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "orders",
         localField: "sku",
         foreignField: "item",
         as: "inventory_docs"
       }
  }
])
```

In this query I am getting all the `inventory's` document matches with `orders` documents

**Expected Result**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "sku" : "abc",
    "description" : "product 1",
    "instock" : 120,
    "inventory_docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "item" : "abc",
            "price" : 12,
            "quantity" : 2
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "sku" : "jkl",
    "description" : "product 4",
    "instock" : 70,
    "inventory_docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "item" : "jkl",
            "price" : 20,
            "quantity" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the expected result?

Comment: @Neodan I think you didn't get my question, I updated my expected result

Comment: did you tried my query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage which skips documents with empty `inventory_docs` field. There no other way to achieve that.

Query:

```
db.getCollection('inventory').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "orders",
            localField: "sku",
            foreignField: "item",
            as: "inventory_docs"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "inventory_docs": {$ne: []}
        }
    }
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "sku" : "abc",
    "description" : "product 1",
    "instock" : 120.0,
    "inventory_docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0,
            "item" : "abc",
            "price" : 12.0,
            "quantity" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : 4.0,
    "sku" : "jkl",
    "description" : "product 4",
    "instock" : 70.0,
    "inventory_docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 2.0,
            "item" : "jkl",
            "price" : 20.0,
            "quantity" : 1.0
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Added the result of my query.

Comment: Is this efficient?

Comment: lookup is only remove particular collection but when using $ne it will returns only those data which was exactly matched to that condition . It will helps me a lot ! Thank You !!